# Bash one liner - Test if a file exists and source if it does other exit with error

Tags: php, bash, testing

In other words I want to make this into a one-liner:

```
    test -e ${MY_HOME}/setup-env.sh || { echo "ERROR: MY_HOME not defined or does not contain srtup-env.sh" 1>&2 ; exit 1; }

    . ${MY_HOME}/setup-env.sh
```

Comment: It's possible to do it on one line but why would you want to? Using a function for this would be easier to read as well as require little typing per use.

Comment: For me real one-liners are those that accomplish required tasks with one uninterrupted instance of a command. And I see those that uses separators like `;` not qualified to be called as such.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use this one liner:

```
[[ -e "${MY_HOME}/setup-env.sh" ]] && source "${MY_HOME}/setup-env.sh" || { echo "ERROR: MY_HOME not defined or does not contain srtup-env.sh" 1>&2 ; exit 1; }
```

Comment: This would also run the message if `source "${MY_HOME}/setup-env.sh"` ends with nonzero status code.

Comment: Yes that's good point, I think that is pitfall of doing this all in one line. Obviously `source "${MY_HOME}/setup-env.sh"` cannot be done in a sub shell.

Answer (score 3):

```
[[ -e ${MY_HOME}/setup-env.sh ]] && { source "${MY_HOME}/setup-env.sh"; exit; }; echo "ERROR: MY_HOME not defined or does not contain setup-env.sh" >&2; exit 1
```

Or if non-bash:

```
test -e "${MY_HOME}/setup-env.sh" && { . "${MY_HOME}/setup-env.sh"; exit; }; echo "ERROR: MY_HOME not defined or does not contain setup-env.sh" >&2; exit 1
```

It's actually not a "one-liner" for me but just a condensed form.